# Strong operator topology is a topology proof

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras

Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a Hilbert space and $U(\mathcal{H})$ be the set of unitary operators on it. We define:
\begin{equation}
V_f(U_0,r):=\{U \in U(\mathcal{H})| \; \; ||U_0(f)-U(f)|| < r \}, \; \; f \in \mathcal{H}, \; r>0.
\end{equation}
We now claim a subset $W$ to be open in $\mathcal{O}_S$, the strong operator topology, iff
\begin{equation}
W \in \mathcal{O}_{S} \iff W=\bigcup_{U_0 \in W} \bigcap_{j=1}^{k} V_{f_j}(U_0,r_j).
\end{equation}
Why does the collection of such open sets define a topology?

My trial so far is this: $\varnothing \in \mathcal{O}_S$, as we would take empty union. And empty union is the empty set. Moreover, it is also true that:
\begin{equation}
U_0 \in V_f(U_0,r), \; \; \text{since} \; \;||U_0(f) - U_0(f)||=0 <r.
\end{equation}
To show that the set $U(\mathcal{H})$ also belongs to the topology, we have to show:
\begin{equation}
U(\mathcal{H})=\bigcup_{U_0 \in \mathcal{H}} \bigcap_{j=1}^{k} V_{f_j}(U_0,r_j),
\end{equation}
We do this by double inclusion. Let $A \in U(\mathcal{H})$. Then, we have by the above observation that
\begin{equation}
A \in V_{f_j}(A,r_j) \; \; \text{for all} \; \; f_j \in \mathcal{H}, \; \; r_j>0.
\end{equation}
This lets us conclude that:
\begin{equation}
A \in \bigcap_{j=1}^{k} V_{f_j}(A,r_j).
\end{equation}
Taking union over all $A\in U(\mathcal{H})$ shows us that:
\begin{equation}
A \in \bigcup_{A \in U(\mathcal{H})} \bigcap_{j=1}^{k} V_{f_j}(A,r_j), \; \; \text{i. e.} \; \; U(\mathcal{H}) \subseteq \bigcup_{A \in U(\mathcal{H})} \bigcap_{j=1}^{k} V_{f_j}(A,r_j)
\end{equation}
Now suppose $A \in \bigcup_{U_0 \in \mathcal{H}}\limits \bigcap_{j=1}^{k} \limits V_{f_j}(U_0,r_j).$ By our above observation, we know:
\begin{equation}
U_0 \in \bigcap_{j=1}^{k} \limits V_{f_j}(U_0,r_j).
\end{equation}
Taking union over all $U_0 \in U(\mathcal{H})$ lets us conclude $A \in U(\mathcal{H}).$ Thus we have successfully shown by double inclusion that
\begin{equation}
U(\mathcal{H})=\bigcup_{U_0 \in W} \bigcap_{j=1}^{k} V_{f_j}(U_0,r_j).
\end{equation}
How to check the other two axioms? There i'm a bit lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition the set $W$ is open iff for any $U_0\in W$ there is a finite collection of $f_j\in \mathcal{H}$ and a collection of positive numbers $r_j,$ $1\le j\le n,$ such that $$\bigcap_{j=1}^nV_{f_j}(U_0,r_j)\subset W$$ Therefore $$W\supset\bigcup_{U_0\in W}\bigcap_{j=1}^nV_{f_j}(U_0,r_j)$$ The reverse containment is obvious. All the elements $n,$ $f_j$ and $r_j$ depend on $W_0,$ so they should be denoted as $n_{W_0},\, f_{j,W_0},\, r_{j,W_0}.$

The set $U(\mathcal{H})$ is open by definition, as it is an entire collection of  unitary operators. If we consider $U(\mathcal{H})$  as a subset of $B(\mathcal{H})$ then $U(\mathcal{H})$ is not open in $B(\mathcal{H})
$